# Runtime Error : GNUPG Not Installed while running on Pycharm in Windows Environment

Tags: python, gnupg, pgp

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
```

I am using this command which gives a runtime error:

```
RuntimeError: GnuPG is not installed!
```

It works finw while using the same on Linux Environment. Can someone help?